# How to apply filter to DataView with Multiple "AND" conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, filtering, dataview, rowfilter

I have a `DataTable` containing the some rows. Which is copied to `DataView`. Now I have IDs in form of `List<string>`. which contains the selected items from `GridView`. Now I want to filter this `DataView` using AND as filter.

When I apply just one it works, but applying multiple `AND` doesn't work.

In .cs :

```
List<string> selectedAddress = new List<string>();
protected DataView GetSelectedItems()
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dtresult);
    int count = selectedAddress.Count();
    if (count > 0)
    {
        string query = "ID=";

        for (int j = 0; j < selectedAddress.Count; j++)
        {
            string val = selectedAddress[j].ToString();
            if (j == 0)
            {
                query += val + " and ";
            }
            else
            {
                query += "ID=" + val + "";
            }
        }
        dv.RowFilter = query;
    }
    return dv;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering DataView with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137020/filtering-dataview-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string> selectedAddress = new List<string>();
protected DataView GetSelectedItems()
{
    DataView dvResult = new DataView(dtresult);
    string query = "";
    int count = selectedAddress.Count();

    for (int j = 0; j < selectedAddress.Count; j++)
    {
        string val = selectedAddress[j].ToString() + ",";
        query += val;
    }

    query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1);
    dvResult.RowFilter = "ID IN(" + query + ")";
    return dvResult;
}
```

Comment: great @Somnath..its too long time but this works fine..! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) The value has to be within quotation marks.
So the following should work:

```
dv.RowFilter = "ID = '23' or ID = '46'";
```

Anyway when your list contains the IDs to show then the operator should be OR and not AND as there should be no row in the table having two IDs at the same time.